# Can I use direct-post on authorize.net to auto pay?

Tags: php, authorize.net

I was wondering if it was possible to use authorize.net to auto pay for some customers that have a monthly payment. For example if there was a way to link their credit card account and the account on my server. My site doesn't have SSL yet but the authorize.net makes a secure https post so I use the DPM method to accept payments

Comment: http://www.authorize.net/solutions/merchantsolutions/merchantservices/automatedrecurringbilling/

Answer (score 4):

Whether or not you can, you shouldn't.  Authorize.net exposes an [Automated Recurring Billing API](http://developer.authorize.net/api/arb/) which you should use for this task.  If you're taking people's money, do it the right way.  A serious downside of your approach is that you'd need to store credit card information on your own system, which is at best a bad idea and at worst breaking the law depending on where you are.